# Cannot read property x of 'undefined' with ternary condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a table with a dropdown menu that will filter the data shown. It loads correctly and I can toggle the individual teams but when I try to select All Teams (index 0) again I get an error saying property 'name' is undefined.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { flavours } from "./mock-data";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedFilter, setFilter] = useState(0);

  // start table
  const header = [
    { title: "Banana" },
    { title: "Chocolate" },
    { title: "Vanilla" },
    { title: "Total" }
  ];
  // render Table Headers
  const renderTableHeader = () =>
    header.map((e, index) => {
      const { title } = e;
      return (
        <th key={Number(index)}>
          {title}
        </th>
      );
    });
  const renderAllTeamData = () =>
    flavours.map((team) => {
      const { name, banana, chocolate, vanilla } = team; // destructuring
      return (
        <tr key={team.name}>
          <th
            style={{ textAlign: "start" }}
          >
            {name}
          </th>
          <td>{banana.length}</td>
          <td>{chocolate}</td>
          <td>{vanilla}</td>
          <td>
            {banana.length + chocolate + vanilla}
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  const renderTeamData = () => {
    const { name, banana, chocolate, vanilla } = flavours[selectedFilter - 1]; // destructuring
    return (
      <tr>
        <th style={{ textAlign: "start" }}>
          {name}
        </th>
        <td>{banana.length}</td>
        <td>{chocolate}</td>
        <td>{vanilla}</td>
        <td>{banana.length + chocolate + vanilla}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <select
          value={selectedFilter}
          onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}
        >
          <option value={0}>All Teams</option>
          {flavours.map((value, index) => (
            <option key={value.name} value={index + 1}>
              {value.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </form>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> </th>
            {renderTableHeader()}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {selectedFilter === 0 ? renderAllTeamData() : renderTeamData()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a code sandbox too https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-brattain-pwnbr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here

```
      {selectedFilter === 0 ? renderAllTeamData() : renderTeamData()}
```

Here you are using === which is comparing against value and type but you set the currentTarget.value which is a string, so the comparison fails and moved to the else part

```
  <select
      value={selectedFilter}
      onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}
    >
```

You can fix by changing it to compare by value like below

```
      {selectedFilter == 0 ? renderAllTeamData() : renderTeamData()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `e.currentTarget.value` to Int.
replace that line with :
`onChange={(e) => setFilter(parseInt(e.currentTarget.value, 10))}`
and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

change the onchange function of your select

```
 <select
      value={selectedFilter}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setFilter(+e.currentTarget.value);
      }}
    >
      <option value={0}>All Teams</option>
      {flavours.map((value, index) => (
        <option key={value.name} value={index + 1}>
          {value.name}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
```

or change tbody like this

```
<tbody>
      {selectedFilter == 0 ? renderAllTeamData() : renderTeamData()}
    </tbody>
```

the problem in current scenario is the value u set is integer or number but value u select come as string

Answer (score 0):

Convert the filter value to a number before setting it to state.

`setFilter(+e.currentTarget.value)`

```
const [selectedFilter, setFilter] = useState(0);

 <form>
        <select
          value={selectedFilter}
          onChange={(e) => setFilter(+e.currentTarget.value)}
        >
          <option value={0}>All Teams</option>
          {flavours.map((value, index) => (
            <option key={value.name} value={index + 1}>
              {value.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </form>
```